# SSIS - Lookup Failing

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a process whereby I need to provide 2 files, 1 for New Business and 1 for Adjustments.

Originally I did this all in an SP that outputted the information to temp tables that I then output to a File but this has its drawbacks.

The problem I have is a I use a Lookup to compare yesterday 'Live' Table with Today's Live Table. Any unmatched rows are considered New Policies therefore I output them to the New File - Works Fine.

Adjustments are then done based on the Make/Model/Car Reg and Address1/2/3/4 & PCode of any given policy being different.

What I need to do is use a Lookup to test every case from my currently live table (Table A) against yesterdays live cases (Table B) and check for ONLY where the above details are different.

The problem I am having at the moment is the Lookup is also pulling in cases where the Value is 'NULL' as in the New Business cases, which I don't want to be included as they are already in another file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are the tables in the same database? Use an `EXISTS` or `OUTER JOIN` to do this in the database.

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid I know with the database but ideally I wanted to do it direct within SSIS. I will just do it within the DB if I can't find a raw SSIS solution.

Comment: Ideally I would do it all in the database. But anyway can't you put a `WHERE Field IS NOT NULL` in the offending part of the lookup? This might require a no cache lookup (which means it calls the lookup sql row by row). This is a reason I don't like SSIS - it's inferior to a single SQL query with a join (which is set based not row by row)